# How to get the parameters passed by <s:url.. struts tag in the action class

Tags: struts, tags

M sending the parameters from the jsp page, the code is

```
  <s:url id="url" action="searchAction">
    <s:param name="id">"${cgConsultant.id}"</s:param>
     </s:url>
```

and m getting it in the url as..

```
http://localhost:8080/search/searchAction.html?id="1"
```

I need to get it in the action class how do i get it..
please do any suggestion for that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a

```
public void setId(String id) {
}
```

method and give it an implementation.